# How to fix the position of the icon on the right over the image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

> PS: I'm very new to CSS and I'm trying my head around to work on a
>   mobile responsive UI, so please spare me if anything silly!

I have an image, to the left of the image I'm showing a text and to the right I'm showing an Icon. However I'm unable to **fix the position of the Icon**. It **keeps changing**. Below are the images for the reference.

[image: The one which is working]

[image: The one which is not working]

Below is my code

```css
.banner-image {
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.text-over-image {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -180px;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right!important;
}

.mt-45 {
  margin-top: -45px;
}

.mr-25 {
  margin-right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="banner-image" src="/assets/productionBanner@3x.png" alt="Productionbanner@3x">
  <div class="text-over-image">
    <h4 class="title-font">Speed Management</h4>
    <h5>- Exploring 3 interactions that creates great impact</h5>
    <a href="/user_profiles/2/user_notes/new?book_summary_id=3">
      <img height="15" width="15" class="mt-45 pull-right mr-25" src="/assets/Add@2x.png" alt="Add@2x">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts and suggestions to solve the problem are very much appreciated!

Comment: The uploaded images are not showing up for some reason. If anyone can fix it would be very helpful

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357690/imgur-returning-503-service-unavailable?cb=1

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Aah! Thanks! What a bad timing it is!

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I got the images working! Can you take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've figured out the issue. The issue is the icon is placed inside the div where the context is dynamic and their position is fixed. So I moved the icon out of the div and tweaked the css and it worked! This is what I came up with

```
<div>
  <img class="banner-image" src="/assets/productionBanner@3x.png" alt="Productionbanner@3x">
  <a href="/user_profiles/2/user_notes/new?book_summary_id=1">
    <img height="15" width="15" class="mt-125 pull-right add-note" src="/assets/Add@2x.png" alt="Add@2x">
  </a>  
  <div class="text-over-image">
    <h4 class="title-font">The 5 Appreciation Languages</h4>
    <h5>- Learn how to lead, inspire and engage through appreciation</h5> 
  </div>
</div>

.banner-image {
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.text-over-image {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -180px;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right!important;
}

.mt-125 {
  margin-top: -125px;
}
.add-note{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%
}
```